# Intellij - various locations to set Java version

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can see at least four different locations in an Intellij (2019.1 CE) Java project to set the Java version:

a. pom.xml

b. File | Project Structure | Project | Project SDK

c. File | Project Structure | Modules | Language level

d. File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler | Target bytecode version

In addition to setting target and source in the pom why are the additional settings required and what is each setting doing that others don't? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Maven (and Gradle) based project you specify source/target versions in pom.xml (build.gradle) file. Based on this IDE sets the module's language Level (corresponds to maven **source** option) and Target bytecode version (corresponds to maven *target** option).

The JDK - is the actual JDK version against which you compile your code. it should be set explicitly by you (since the source/target options not necessarily could correspond to actual JDK you want to compile against.